# DAX Lookup function in Dax sometimes working

Tags: debugging, powerbi, dax

I have 2 Fact tables that aren't related.
I need to create a calc column "vlookup" style from table 1 to table 2
it works sometimes... on the same customer it will and will not work. how?!

[image]

all the conditions for the lookup are the same. how am i getting a blank value where clearly I should get "VirtualPay2"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need measure

```
measure =
CALCULATE (
    MAX ( t1[Gateway] ),
    TREATAS (
        SUMMARIZE ( t2, t2[PSP_ID], t2[pin/login], t2[Date], t2[Hour], t2[amount] ),
        t1[PSP_ID],
        t1[pin/login],
        t1[Date],
        t1[Hour],
        t1[amount]
    )
)
```

if you need a calculated column

```
CalculatedColumn =
CALCULATE (
    CALCULATE (
        MAXX ( t1, t1[Gateway] ),
        TREATAS (
            SUMMARIZE ( t2, t2[PSP_ID], t2[pin/login], t2[Date], t2[Hour], t2[amount] ),
            t1[PSP_ID],
            t1[pin/login],
            t1[Date],
            t1[Hour],
            t1[amount]
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: amazing! it works! (the measure works but the calc col doesn't)
but how? could you explain the code plz?